# Filter with d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a big problem.

I use d3 to visualize my (poll)data. (So Questions and answers) It works fine except one problem.

Sometimes it doesn't visualize the data like they are. For example one time d3 get all right data about d3.json. But the graph is not right. It should load 300 answers in the first bars but it just show 50. I tested it and the json works. 
I tried to filter the graph and I got the same problem.

This is my d3 code.

```
<div>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script>
        var margin = {
                top: 20,
                right: 30,
                bottom: 30,
                left: 430
            },
            width = 1400 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
            .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yScale)
            .orient("left")
            .ticks(10);

        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("class", "chart");

        var chart = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        d3.json("getdata.php", function(error, data) {
            xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {
                return d.text;
            }));
            yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
                return d.count;
            })]);

            chart.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter()

            .append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return xScale(d.text);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d.count);
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return height - yScale(d.count);
                })
                .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())

            chart.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            chart.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 6)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Antworten");

        });

        function type(d) {
            d.count = +d.text;
            return d;
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

I guess the problem starts here. But I don't know why. The problem doesn't appear at every question. Only at a few or when I try to use my filter.

Maybe it happens when two values have a big difference?

Update:
It is like: D3 doesn't want to lose the smallest bar. So other bars must based on that smallest. And then the values are not correct for the bigger bars. Maybe the Y scale depends on the smallest bar.

Comment: Maybe this code could be a problem:
  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
                return d.count;
            })]);